# IntelliJ Idea 12.0 - Shows Javascript errors that doesn't exist

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using **IntelliJ Idea 12.0**, sometimes it shows error in Javascript files that doesn't exist like the picture below. How can I fix this problem? Are there any way to re-validate the source again? Also the 'eye' icon on the top-right corner always is shown in these situations.

[image: Validation Errors even no problems]

Comment: it is cleared the errors but when I type something to files that had errors before invalidating caches, the errors are become visible again.

Answer (score 0):

What version of 12 are you using?  There was an issue related to what you're seeing fixed in 12.1:

[IDEA-101395 Good code is red: JavaScript language injection](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101395)

If you're not on 12.1 you should try upgrading and see if that resolves your problem